# References for this gradient inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a proof or references to the following inequality. Let $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $p = 2d/(d-2)$. Then:
$$\|\nabla f\|_{L^{2}} \ge C\|f\|_{L^{p}}$$
for some constant $C > 0$ which is independent of $f$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this is the socalled Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg%E2%80%93Sobolev_inequality

Comment: Note the $L^p$ exponents in the linked theorem as well as the requirement of compact support. Some more work is required to get the precise inequality you desire

Comment: You can look at the book "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss, in the section about Sobolev's inequalities.